# How to rebuild an sql database for FusionCharts?

Tags: javascript, arrays, fusioncharts

I've written the following to reformat my sql data to fit into a fusion charts readable format. Now that I've 'sounded it out' and am returning the proper format, I'm obviously taking the long route. What is the elegant or efficient/proper method to rebuilding from a database?

```
var chartData = {
    chart: {},
    categories: [],
    dataset: []
};

var category = [];
var dataseries1 = [];
var dataseries2 = [];
var dataseries3 = [];

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * from garage', function(error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;

    for (var i = 0, len = results.length; i < len; i++) {
        category.push({
            label: results[i].date
        });
        dataseries1.push({
            value: results[i].humidity
        });
        dataseries2.push({
            value: results[i].temperature
        });
        dataseries3.push({
            value: results[i].absolute_humidity
        });
    }

    chartData.categories.push({
        category: category
    });

    chartData.dataset.push({
        seriesname: 'Humidity',
        data: dataseries1
    });
    chartData.dataset.push({
        seriesname: 'Temperature',
        data: dataseries2
    });
    chartData.dataset.push({
        seriesname: 'Absolute Humidity',
        data: dataseries3
    });

    console.log(chartData);

});
```

EDIT : The format being returned is

```
{ chart: {},
  categories: [ { category: [Array] } ],
  dataset: 
   [ { seriesname: 'Humidity', data: [Array] },
     { seriesname: 'Temperature', data: [Array] },
     { seriesname: 'Absolute Humidity', data: [Array] } ] }
```

Comment: Depends - does your database understand JSON - can it return it natively?  What do you perceive as being particularly bad about the way you are doing it?

Comment: What database do you use? If you use MongoDB you only get json

Comment: Im using mariadb, the rebuilding is required to fit the fusion charts format for feeding data to their charts as in the rename of "humidity" to "value" in an array, which couldn't hold 3 separate values named value.

Comment: You could convert the result to POJO using JPA and then use Jackson to serilize to JSON. Not sure if that would be the most efficient way to do it, but seems fairly elegant... Might not be worth the effort for only 1 or two queries though...

Comment: Why convert to JSON anyway? You seem to have direct access to the DB, converting the results you get to JSON is useless. What's wrong with simply displaying them directly?

Comment: @Tomalak Fusioncharts doesnt understand the data format as is and storing the data as 'value' 'value' 'value' doesnt work. Fusion is expecting 'label' and 'value' tags to retrieve data and display in their charts.

Comment: Well, "changing the object layout so that Fusioncharts can handle it" and "converting a database response to JSON" are two entirely different things. You don't want to do the latter. Remove all the JSON references from your question, you're confusing people.

Comment: @Tomalak Tag removed and title edited. Thanks for pointing out my confusion.

Comment: Admittedly, FusionCharts itself call it "JSON" (`dataFormat: 'json'`) even though they actually seem to mean "object".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is way too busy with moving data from one temporary place to another. Here is what I would do.

Helper function (this is already contained in many JS tool-belt libraries like lodash):

```
function pluck(property, items) {
    return items.map(function (item) { return item[property]; });
}
```

Usage:

```
connection.connect();
connection.query('SELECT * from garage', function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var chart = new FusionCharts({
        // ...
        dataSource: {
            categories: pluck('date', results),
            dataset: [
                { seriesname: 'Humidity', data: pluck('humidity', results) },
                { seriesname: 'Temperature', data: pluck('temperature', results) },
                { seriesname: 'Absolute Humidity', data: pluck('absolute_humidity', results) }
            ]
        }
    });
    chart.render();
});
```

---

When you have [ES6 arrow-function support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions), the `pluck` helper can be rewritten as follows, if you want to.

```
var pluck = (property, items) => items.map(item => item[property]);
```

Comment: This is the type of interesting example Im looking for. I knew my code was very much 'baby steps sounding it out.' I'll look it over to understand it, I'm throwing an error on copy/paste of unexpected identifier 'dataset'.

Comment: My bad, forgot a comma.

Comment: I added it too, deleted something else while cleaning up my web of code. Very nice example not too hard to comprehend. +1

Comment: This kind of activity is typically called "massaging data", or more formally "transforming" or "mapping".